# I want to divide a pulse in time axis and create more pulses

Tags: signal, signal-processing, pulse, modulation, sampling

I need help with my project. I want to split a pulse on the timeline. I want to take the signal and divide it by 58 μs. Actually the time of the output signal is not important. I just need to generate (input pulse time length) / (58 μs) signal on output. A few people said you can use a clock, but I haven't used clocks other than microprocessors before, how can I use them exactly? If I directly connect the signal to input leg of the clock, can I get a signal from the output divided by frequency as I want? I'm sorry, if it's a stupid question. I'm sure there's a very simple answer and there's a term for it, but I don't know much about it. I've added a picture to make it more descriptive. Sorry for the bad drawing. The upper pulses represent the input, and the lower ones represent the pulses I want to receive at the output.

edit: I can't use microprocessor.

[image].

Comment: Do you want to have an output pulse starting every 58 μs while the input is high?  You cannot have them equally spaced with respect to the input pulse without violating causality.  How long do the output pulses need to be?  What do you want to happen if the input goes low while the output is high?  What do you want to happen if the input pulse is high for 57 μs?  For 57.9μs?

Comment: For the first question yes, I want to have an output pulse starting every 58 μs while the input is high. Actually, I don't need to equally spaced with respect to input pulse. Output pulses must be longer than 3050ns because I'll use bcd to 7 segment decoder (
CD4511). When input low, output should be low. I don't care for 57 μs or 57.9 μs, output can be low. Thanks for your questions.

Comment: What if the final output pulse begins and has to be cut short because the input pulse falls back to zero? Do you want it to continue past the end or cut-short? Draw a more detailed picture of what you want showing timing please.

Comment: It's not important for my application. Every pulse 1 cm in my project and 1 cm mistake can be acceptable for this application.

Comment: Simply you are measuring the period by gating a clock.  This is similar to a frequency counter. Period is fixed clock freq and variable sample time vs freq is variable clock freq and fixed sample  time.

Comment: You might be able to build a logic gate oscillator with an enable signal (NAND type). That way when you apply a enable pulse of 116 us you get two pulses.

Comment: A logic gate oscillator with an enable signal (NAND type) seems like the most feasible one for my project, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ6Rue.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your accuracy requirements aren't extremely stringent, you can use the input signal to control the /RESET pin of a 555 in astable/oscillator mode.  These values should get you close.